# GridView on change of dropdown list selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a gridview. One of the columns in the gridview has a drop down list for all rows. Is it possible to fire a method when any of the gridview drop down boxes selection is changed?

I tried adding the onselectedindexchange for the drop down list in the item template but it did not work.

Any ideas?

```
<Gridview>
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
               <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="No">No</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use selected index changed to suppose this is the dropdown inside your grid

```
<Gridview>
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                  onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
               <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:DropDownList>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</GridView>
```

You can have a function as below

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
     GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.Parent.Parent;
     int idx = row.RowIndex;
     // TextBox txtECustCode = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("txtECustCode");
```

Comment: Thanks to Adil also. I was just missing the autopostback when I gave it a go originally.

Comment: In my code i have two dropdown list in a row, on page load first dropdown has items, upon index changed second drop down list items need to be binded.  +1 for your ans.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [GridView.RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event instead of On SelectedIndex Changed. Also add [AutoPostBack="true"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can use `CommandArguments` to pass the arguements if you need.

```
void ContactsGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
      DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
}
```

Comment: Ahh ok. Does the rowCommand go in the dropdownlist or the gridview? I will give it a go.

Comment: I cannot add CommandName to the drop down list. Everything else is fine.