# How to get data from database to gridview by selecting dropdownlist option?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, ado.net

[image: System Test Image]

I was faced system test round which contains 3 labels, 3 textboxes, 1 button, 1 drop-down list and one grid view controls.

I was inserted into the database using data reader(ADO.NET), but when I failed to display data by selecting the dropdown list into grid view. (Open System Test Image Link to view program design)

Can anyone give a solution for this problem?

Excepted Output:

When you select the drop-down list option(SNumber), it will display data into grid view (which is data related to option selected in the dropdown list).

ex: Select(in dropdownlist) -> 415(SNumber)

[Gridview]

```
+---------+--------+-------------+
| SNumber | SName  | SPercentage |
+---------+--------+-------------+
|     415 |    Nag |    70%      |
+---------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you please show some piece of code done by you ? and where did you got stuck ? or you just want full demo code ?

Comment: You can refer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474557/gridview-on-change-of-dropdown-list-selection
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395592/populate-gridview-from-dropdown-control-c
And there are many more.